# Javascript make click listener extend to all childern

Tags: javascript

I want to make my click listener on specific element extend to all children, this mean that if I click inside any element, it will show a simple console.log message.

Here is my code =>

```
<div class="x">
    <span id="a">hello</span>
    <p name="b"> this is p tag!</p>
    <div>this is div</div>
    <div name="c" id="c">one more div</div>
    <a>just a tag test</a>
</div>


document.querySelectorAll('[class="x > *"]').onclick = function(e) {
    return console.log('clicked!')
}
```

Currently, if I click on "X" class or anchor tag, I do not receive the console.log message. How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`; setting `.onclick` on a `NodeList` does nothing.

You have two choices:

- Set a handler on each of the elements: `document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => el.onclick = handler)`, or better yet, `document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', handler))`
- Set a handler on an ancestor element, and let it catch the event as it propagates up the tree.